# How would a linked list be faster in iteration? with __iter__ and __next__ or with __getitem__?

Tags: python, performance, linked-list

I am basically trying to emulate some characteristics of python's lists with the following linked list:

```
class List:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.length = 0

    def append(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            tail = self.tail
            tail.next = node
            self.tail = node
        self.length += 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i >= len(self):
            raise IndexError("Index out of range.")
        elif i < len(self):
            index = 0
            current = self.head
            while index <= i:
                if index == i:
                    return current
                current = current.next
                index += 1

    def __contains__(self, value):
        for node in self:
            if value == node.value:
                return True
        return False

class Node:

    def __init__(self, value, n=None):
        self.next = n
        self.value = value
```

So I need to make this linked list as efficient as possible, specially when looping through a big instance of it. Is there any way to improve my **getitem** implementation or an alternative use of **iter** and **next** to maximize performance **without using any kind of python's built-in data structures**, such as lists or tuples? If anyone could come up with any code examples, I would be grateful.

Comment: If you need a linked list in Python you can simply use `collections.deque` (to some extent). Since its guts are written in C, it will be faster and more efficient than your stuff in pure Python.

Comment: I added my two cents already, but I would like to know what are your reasons to use a linked list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be slightly more efficient, since it gets rid of some variable assignments and comparisons.

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    if i >= len(self):
        raise IndexError("Index out of range.")

    current = self.head
    for _ in xrange(i):
        current = current.next

    return current
```

However, random access on a linked list will be always at least `O(n)`. If you are not looking for random access but pure iteration, `__iter__` is the way to go, because iterating with the combination of `__len__` and `__getitem__`  will be `O(n^2)`, which is quite horrible. You can do something like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    current = self.head

    while current:
        yield current
        current = current.next
```

You don't have to provide any `__next__` or `next` method. `yield`ing from a method is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Define `__iter__`: return an iterator that keeps a reference to the current node.  Then it can get the next node in `O(1)`.  `__getitem__` traverses to the requested node in `O(n)`.

Comment: Could you be more explicative and provide a code example, please? I'd appreciate it very much.

Comment: I didn't provide a code example because this sounds like a homework assignment.  Other answers show the code using a generator to maintain the state.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `__iter__` method:

```
def __iter__(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
        yield current
        current = current.next
```

Comment: Just change the loop to `while current:` and remove the condition. Would also deal with an empty list.

Comment: A linked list always breaks, when it contains two equal objects!

Comment: @achampion, and what if `None` is contained in the list?

Comment: None as a value in the Node, would be `Node.value,` which is never referenced. Should work fine as this will only exit when the Node is None (i.e. end of list).